# Can anyone tell me where these values are coming from in this assmbly code?

Tags: assembly, chess, emu8086

[image: 1]

I got this code from youtube. It's the code to move pawn in the chess game.I am also attaching the source code which I got from youtube https://github.com/r1fl/8086-Assembly-Chess
here is the code.

```
moves@validateMove:
        pawn@moves:
            xor cx, cx

            cmp [byte si], 0
            jg black@pawn

            white@pawn:
                pawn1@white:
                    mov bx, si
                    **sub bx, 8**

                    cmp [byte bx], 0
                    jne pawn2@white

                    push bx
                    inc cx

                pawn2@white:
                    mov bx, offset board@engine
                    **add bx, 48d**

                    cmp si, bx
                    jb pawn3@white

                    mov bx, offset board@engine
                    **add bx, 55d**

                    cmp si, bx
                    ja pawn3@white

                    mov bx, si
                    **sub bx, 16d**
                    push bx
                    inc cx
```

The board init code (https://github.com/r1fl/8086-Assembly-Chess/blob/8e317f2aa05f1ee843f3bf3b0e7fc196f0ae8e7a/engine.inc#L11) shows that it's using a byte array for the board, and a similar style of address math for the array indexing.

Comment: Please don't post images of code (or text in general). Instead copy-paste the text *as text* into the question. If you want to mark out some specific code then add a comment on the line.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what `si` contains here. But `offset board@engine + 48` and `offset board@engine + 55` presumably represent the addresses of squares A2 and H2 on the board.

Comment: Ok, so I'm guessing that `si` is the current position of the pawn. So `si-8` is the address of the square directly above, `si-16` is the address of the square two steps above, `si-7` is the address of the square above and to the right, and `si-9` is the address of the square above and the left. Assuming that you're familiar with how pawns are allowed to move, it should be pretty clear why the code is checking those locations specifically.

Comment: @Michael: Yeah, the board init code (https://github.com/r1fl/8086-Assembly-Chess/blob/8e317f2aa05f1ee843f3bf3b0e7fc196f0ae8e7a/engine.inc#L11) shows what values it uses for pieces/pawns in a 64-byte array.  (And the inefficient code this uses, like `add` instead of addressing modes like `[board@engine + bx]`, let alone `rep stosb` to zero the board.)

Answer (score 0):

- n forward p right = `n*8 - p`
- n forward p left = `n*8 + p`

- n backward p right = `n*8 + p`
- n backward p left = `n*8 - p`

This was the actual logic of the board